# how to change displayed images in pysimplegui

Tags: image, base64, pysimplegui

I've created the GUI as per following code.
Is it feasible to change the displayed image with a new one by clicking on the image button, so that the new image can be saved when the form is updated?
Moreover, is it feasible to display only the filled fields once the updated (and saved) form is uploaded?
Thanks in advance

```
# ----------- Importing Libraries ---------------

import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime
import base64


sg.theme('DarkTeal9')      
#------------------------------Create single layouts----------------------------------

flower_base64 = "image code here"

layout_img = [[sg.Button('', image_data=flower_base64, button_color=(sg.theme_background_color(),sg.theme_background_color()),border_width=0, key='-GRAPH-')]]


   
layout_1 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT2-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST2-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN2-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN2-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9')]]


layout_a = [[sg.Button("row 2")]]

layout_2 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT3-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST3-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN3-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN3-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9')]]

layout_b =[[sg.Button("row 3")]]

layout_3 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT4-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1), visible=True),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST4-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN4-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN4-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9', justification="c")]]

#------------------------------Create master layout----------------------------------
               
layout = [[sg.Column(layout_img, key="-AZZ-")],
          [sg.Column(layout_1, key='-LAY1-'), sg.Column(layout_a, visible=True, key="-LAYA-")],
          [sg.Column(layout_2, visible=False, key='-LAY2-'), sg.Column(layout_b, visible=False, key='-LAYB-')],
          [sg.Column(layout_3, visible=False, key='-LAY3-')],
          [sg.Button ("Save"), sg.Button ("Load"), sg.Button("Upload"), sg.Button('Exit')]]
        

window = sg.Window("", layout, no_titlebar=True)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
        
    if event == 'Save':
        filename = sg.popup_get_file("Save", save_as=True, no_window=True)
        window.SaveToDisk(filename)
    if event == 'Load':
        filename = sg.popup_get_file('Load', no_window=True)
        window.LoadFromDisk(filename)
        if "-IT2-":
            window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
            window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        if "-IT3-":
            window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
            
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
        window.close()
    if event == 'row 2':
        window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
        window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        window[f'-LAYB-'].update(visible=True)
        layout = str(event)
    if event == 'row 3':
        window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
        window[f'-LAYB-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = str(event)

window.close()
```

Comment: Try [User settings API](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#:~:text=indicates%20running%20Windows-,UserSettings%20API%20%2D%20Class%20Interface,-The%20User%20Settings), maybe you need to save/load your image(s) by yourself.

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for the quick reply. Much appreciated. Actually, I am not so familiar with python (I am started to use it two months ago), however the form can be saved and uploaded, even thought when reopened the form shows all the fields and not only the filled ones. Moreover, what about my question on changing picture?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script, just for demo, and there's only one Image element to save and to load in the GUI.

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg

settings_file = 'settings.json'
settings = {'-Image-':None}

if Path(settings_file).is_file():
    with open(settings_file, 'rt') as f:
        settings = json.load(f)

layout = [
    [sg.FileBrowse(target='Browse', enable_events=True, key='Browse')],
    [sg.Image(filename=settings['-Image-'], visible=(settings['-Image-'] is not None), key='-Image-')],
]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Browse':
        filename = values['Browse']
        window['-Image-'].update(filename=filename, visible=True)
        window.refresh()
        window.move_to_center()
        settings['-Image-'] = filename

with open(settings_file, 'wt') as f:
    json.dump(settings, f)

window.close()
```

Comment: Basically the suggested approach is fine with me; unfortunately is not possible to save the form with the attached image

Comment: What you mean thr "form" ? You can restore all required elements with saved value, here Image element just an example, not mean to save your form in GUI as image.

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry, do not consider my last comment. Actually your suggestion works very well. Thanks!! What about the possibility to "load" the saved GUI(I mean the form/template with filled fields) in which only the filled fields are displayed. Currently all fields are showed

Comment: Just another curiosity: after the file is saved (i.e. with a new name) is it possible to have the original one without any image, so that the original file can work as a kind of "master template" (allowing to upload any image and then save it each time in a new file)?

Comment: After window shown, close the window directly, then you got the master template. Set `visible=(settings['-Image-'] is not None)` to hide the Image element if image filename is `None`.